# static_cast derived this object to base class in C++

Tags: c++, derived-class, static-cast, effective-c++

When reading Item 27 Minimize casting in **Effective C++**, it says do not try to use `static_cast` to cast `*this` in derived class to base class. It because **`static_cast<Base>(*this)` will create a temporary object of Base class**. I tried an example as follows, however, it always output 10 using different compilers such as clang 3.8 and gcc 4.9, 5.3.

Am I wrong?

```
  #include <iostream>

  class A {
  public:
    int a;
    virtual void foo() {std::cout << a << std::endl;}
  };

  class B : public A {
  public:
    int b;
    void foo ()  { static_cast<A>(*this).foo();}
  };


  int main () {
    B b;
    b.a = 10;
    b.foo();

    return 0;
  }
```

The question is why `static_cast` will create a temporary object.

Comment: Why wouldn't it print 10?

Comment: What's the question? What's the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Effective c++ says static_cast(*this) will create a temporary object of Base class. So under such assumption, I think it should output 0. Is this correct?

Comment: Why should it output 0? The temporary is created as if by `A(*this)`. Consider which constructor that uses.

Comment: @KerrekSB Thanks. I understand now. Actually, I created this wired example and want to verify if a temporary object is created. This example is not good for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

A more meaningful example would be this one:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
    virtual void foo() { std::cout << "A" << std::endl; }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    virtual void foo() { std::cout << "B" << std::endl; }
    void bar ()  { static_cast<A>(*this).foo(); }
};

int main () {
    B b;
    b.bar();
}
```

I'd expect `bar` to print `B`, for `foo` is an overridden method. It prints `A` instead.
Well, that's right from the the point of view of the language, not so good from the point of view of the developer that was expecting a completely different result.

It works if you use instead the following class:

```
class B : public A {
public:
    virtual void foo() { std::cout << "B" << std::endl; }
    void bar ()  { static_cast<A*>(this)->foo(); }
};
```

Also the following one works as expected (added for the sake of clarity, thanks to @MORTAL in the comments):

```
class B : public A {
public:
    virtual void foo() { std::cout << "B" << std::endl; }
    void bar ()  { static_cast<A&>(*this).foo(); }
};
```

Anyway, the problem you are facing with is named *slicing*.
That's why using `static_cast<A>(*this)` is discouraged if you don't know what you are doing.

See [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing) for further details.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I want to create an example to verify static_cast<A>(*this) will create a temporary object. But I screwed up myself.

Comment: The example in the answer actually creates a temporary object.

Comment: i would prefer `static_cast<A&>(*this).foo()` instead of `static_cast<A*>(this)->foo()`

Comment: @MORTAL Right, both of them work as expected, I picked up one for the answer. Anyway, answer updated.

Comment: About expecting printing A or B: Actually that *was* what I expected – as not casting to pointer or reference, I *expected* object slicing occurring and even tried to profit from – not fully sure about the temporary (fearing that, though), so I stumbled upon here – discovering (and being confirmed by own tests) the temporary is indeed created, breaking my attempt for a solution to my problem...

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you do not modify the value of `A`'s `a` variable, thus you do not see a change between the values of the two instances.

Add the following copy constructor for `A`:

```
A() = default; // so that it still exists...
A(A const& other)
    : a(other.a + 1) // initialise to a value definitely differing...
{ }
```

*Now* you should see 11 instead, confirming the statement...

Comment: I know – late answer... Stumbled upon here on search for a solution to another problem – tested myself with the same approach.

Answer (score -1):

First of all you don't have to cast Derived -> Base because it happens automatically. And yes, static_cast will create an object of type which you casting to. 
In your case to enable polymorphism you can use either references or pointers:

```
int main(){
    B b;
    A &a = b; // no explicit cast needed
    a.foo(); // will call B::foo

    //OR

    B *bPtr = new B;
    A *aPtr = bPtr; // no explicit cast needed
    aPtr->foo(); // same as above
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I want to create an example to verify static_cast<A>(*this) will create a temporary object. But I screwed up myself.